# using PHP's GD to create text with different colors for letters in same word

Tags: php, image, text, colors, gd

I am trying to create a PNG using PHP to create text with 2 separate colors. As you can see, `$text = "bluewhite";`. Currently I have the code to create the entire `$text` appear as white, but I would like the `"blue"` inside `$text` to be blue and the "white" in `$text` to be `white`.

Here is the updated php code to create the white text from `$text`.

```
$text = strtoupper('bluewhite');
$font = 'font.ttf';

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(1200, 2100);

imagealphablending($im, true);
imagesavealpha($im, true);

$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 66, 139, 200);

$bluetext = imagettftext($im, 100, 0, 0, 120, $blue, $font, substr($text, 0, 4));

imagettftext($im, 100, 0, 321, 120, -$black, $font, substr($text, 4));

$crop = imagecrop($im, ['x' => 0, 'y' => 0, 'width' => 900, 'height' => 140]);

imagealphablending($crop, false);
imagesavealpha($crop, false);

$clear = imagecolorallocate($crop, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($crop, $clear);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($crop, null, 9);
imagedestroy($crop);
```

Edit: I was about to achieve the above the first 4 letters to be blue and the rest to be white, but my new issue now is that there is different padding between the 2 different color words and I cannot figure out how to keep them the same padding when the words as they change. I'm assuming it's due to the font width of every character adding up, but I'm not sure if there's an easier solution that calculating the width of every letter then to add it up to calculate the correct width needed after the blue letters and then add the extra padding for the white letters to start.

Here are examples of what I'm talking about:

[image: As you can see there is too much space after the blue text, where the white text starts]

[image: and for some words, the spacing between the blue and white letters are perfect, which is what I'm trying to achieve every time]

[image: for some words there is no spacing at all]

sometimes there is too much text after the blue letters, sometimes none at all and sometimes it's perfect. I need this to work for all words and can't figure out how to get the correct spacing in `imagettftext()`

Comment: _"and I believe there must be a native way to achieve this goal."_ - sure - call `imagettftext` twice, once for each part of the text, and with a different color. You will have to _calculate_ the correct position for the second part to start then, of course. `imagettfbbox` can be used to "measure" the dimensions of a text.

Comment: I managed to achieve this, but came across a new issue.  I edited my original post in hopes of finding a solution.

Comment: Show what code you're actually using now. _"but I'm not sure if there's an easier solution that calculating the width of every letter to add it up to calculate the correct spacing needed after the blue letters"_ - did you use `imagettfbbox`, as I suggested?

Comment: ```imagettfbbox``` fixed this, thank you so much for your help!